# Map not showing complete value in lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am returning a map with -

> DEBUG|mapCustomerCentricData{Assortment=10.0, Availability=12.0,
>   Convenience=12.0, Internationalization=null}

when i am returning it to lightning

```
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //set response value in wrapperList attribute on component.
            var StoreResponse = 
          response.getReturnValue().customerCentricDataMap;
            component.set('v.fullMap', StoreResponse);
            for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
                arrayOfMapKeys.push(singlekey);
            }

        }
```

arrayOfMapKeys is showing only key which has data m but i want to display null value as a blank in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem here:

```
for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
            arrayOfMapKeys.push(singlekey);
        }
```

arrayOfMapKeys should be javascript object. Try to change it into this:

```
let arrayOfMapKeys = {};
for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
    arrayOfMapKeys[singlekey] = StoreResponse[singlekey];
}
console.log("arrayOfMapKeys => ",arrayOfMapKeys);
```